# Java GWT server programming handling GET/POST requests

Tags: java, http, gwt, web-applications

I am new to java programming in the web environment and am having trouble understanding the flow.

For an assignment coming up I need to build a web application accessible with an API via get/post requests. For the tutorials that I have followed here is the flow I understand.

User visits top domain->
Per configuration user is directed to a jsp page->
Jsp contains javascrip and html. To access server code (for database, computations and other processes) the jsp page can use RCP to make async requests to a java servlet->
Java servlet does server handling and returns response to jsp page

Is this the required flow or can a user directly acess a servlet, and can that servlet handle get/post, or do I have to handle at the jsp and foward to the servlet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Servlets can be accessed directly. You just need to extend `HttpServlet` and implement `doGet` and/or `doPost`. For example:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException {

        Integer param = null;
        try {
            param = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("param"));
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

You also need to map your servlet to url in `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.adam.test.server.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/my_servlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Now you can access your servlet using url like this:
http://domain.com/my_servlet?param=123

Comment: Thank you very much. Haven't tried it out, but it makes since.